# How to set scroll for Jquery Gantt Chart to todays date

Tags: jquery, charts, gantt-chart

I am using [jQuery Gantt Chart](http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/).
I want to set the default scroll to Today's date.
Currently its taking the least start date of all the records and it starts from there.
Instead it should be to today's date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right there in the docs: Set `scrollToToday` to `true`.

```
$(".selector").gantt({
   ....
   'scrollToToday': true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to here for the bug and code fix
https://github.com/taitems/jQuery.Gantt/issues/52